# How do i configure the django rest framework pagination url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

when I get an object in django rest framework the urls always come absolute with localhost, but in production im going through a proxy on nginx, is there a way to set this url in the settings

Example

```
count: 11
next: "http://localhost:8000/api/accounts/?ordering=-date_registered&page=2"
previous: null
```

I need it to be

```
count: 11
next: "http:/example.com/api/accounts/?ordering=-date_registered&page=2"
previous: null
```

----------  edit --------------------------

please see my complete nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 123.123.123.123;
    root            /home/admin/www/site-web/dist;
    index           index.html;
    charset         utf-8;


    location /static/ {
        alias /home/admin/www/site/static/;
    }

    location /media/  {
        alias /home/admin/www/site/media/;
    }

    location /nginx_status/ {
        # Turn on nginx stats
        stub_status on;
        # I do not need logs for stats
        access_log  off;
        # Security: Only allow access from 192.168.1.100 IP #
        # allow 192.168.1.100;
        # Send rest of the world to /dev/null #
        # deny all;
   }

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

       if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            #
            # Om nom nom cookies
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
             }

        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }

        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
         }
    }

   location /docs/ {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/;
       break;
   }

   location /api/ {
       underscores_in_headers on;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/;
       break;
   }

   location /admin/ {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/;
       break;
   }

}
```

==== super edit====

## Sorry guys, i had 'underscores_in_headers on;' i removed it and all is working

================

Comment: How do you proxying your django server?

Comment: You should really include (relevant parts of) your nginx configuration for the proxy in your question, as that's likely where the problem is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` in your settings to `True` and make sure you pass it along using your web server(proxy) as well.

When django does `build_absolute_uri()` it calls `get_host()` - see below in django.http.request:

```
def get_host(self):
    """Returns the HTTP host using the environment or request headers."""
    # We try three options, in order of decreasing preference.
    if settings.USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST and (
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST' in self.META):
        host = self.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']
        ...
```

See [Real life usage of the X-Forwarded-Host header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084340/real-life-usage-of-the-x-forwarded-host-header)

Comment: i have set USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST=True and in nginx i added 'proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host 123.123.123.123' where 123.123.123.123 is my ip address, but there is no change(i restarted gunicorn and nginx)

Comment: did you look at the headers to see what is getting passed?

Comment: i cant debug since its in production, i updated my post with my config

Comment: What if the proxy is forwarding http to https?

Comment: I'll answer my own question - you need `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` and ensure the header is set.

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like your `Host` header is not being set properly, which would be an issue in your nginx configuration. The issue is that your `Host` header that is being sent includes the port number, so Django is including the port number when building out urls. This will cause future issues with CSRF, because CSRF checks do strict port checking when you are not debugging.

[This is known to cause issues with SSL for similar reasons.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26435272/359284)

You can fix this by setting the `Host` header within Nginx to not include the proxied port.

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

Note that I used the `$http_host` variable instead of `$host` or `$host:$server_port`. This will ensure that Django will still respect CSRF requests on non-standard ports, while still giving you the correct absolute urls.

Comment: i had already added that, please see my updated question with my full config file

Comment: sorry i dont have enough reputation, i upvoted your answer