# Modify the `Host` header or pass `X-Forwarded-Host` when using Nginx as a reverse proxy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy and the upstream server is an ASP.NET Core application where I've registered the [`ForwardedHeadersMiddleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer), which will read three different `X-Forwarded-*` headers:

- `X-Forwarded-For`
- `X-Forwarded-Proto`
- `X-Forwarded-Host`

Now, I understand the first two, but find the last one (`X-Forwarded-Host`) confusing. It seems to me that effectively this has the same effect as just having the proxy rewrite the `Host` header, and I've seen Nginx reverse proxy configurations doing exactly that, like so:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

But then I've also seen the `X-Forwarded-Host` being used instead:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}
```

In some cases both are used at the same time — which makes zero sense to me:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}
```

I'm not sure what I should do. Why would you use both at the same time? Isn't it more idiomatic (or more "correct") to use `X-Forwarded-Host` (if your upstream server supports it) than rewriting `Host`? Changing `Host` feels like a hack to me. I've noticed that the result in my ASP.NET Core app will be the same regardless of whether I set `Host` or `X-Forwarded-Host` (or both), in either case, [`HttpContext.Request.Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httprequest-host) is set to the expected value — provided that the forwarded headers middleware is registered, of course.

To my surprise, I couldn't find any relevant information on this issue by googling, so I had to ask this here. What is the right approach to take in this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real life usage of the X-Forwarded-Host header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084340/real-life-usage-of-the-x-forwarded-host-header)

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I don't think so, I did actually check out that question before posting mine.

Comment: Your app might need two different hosts. a) the domain of the app itself (e.g. "app1.myinternalcluster") and the external domain, required for e.g. `<a href="https://myapp1.example/path">`. So we need the `Host` header to tell the backend server which app should be started and the `X-Forwarded-Host` to allow the app to know the external host. IF your .Net app has it's own IP and it doesn't matter which Host you set, then there should not be a difference. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: In modern environments like kubernetes it's quite common, that every app has its own IP but imagine an example where we run 5 PHP apps and want to run them on two servers with a reverse proxy to allow us to shutdown one server and keep the app running. Here we would need the Host header to tell the backend server which of those 5 apps should be used and the X-Forwarded-Host header to allow the PHP app to output the correct external host.